# What is the spawn rate of Witches in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Now that witches can spawn anywhere what is their spawn rate compared to other mobs?

Comment: Witches have been able to spawn anywhere for a while now, it's actually kinda annoying...

Comment: Yeah i Know, thats why i want to know the rate so that i know if a few things i try to do can increase or decrease it. ITS IN THE NAME OF SCIENCE

Comment: "Science", have fun! *flashes seal of approval*

Comment: here is a wiki article on witch farming that may help some: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Witch_farming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of articles about spawning conditions:

Here is a really good article about spawning rates and conditions
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn

> - Witches will spawn in Witch Huts.
> - When a villager gets struck by lightning, it is replaced by a newly spawned witch
> - Most biomes can spawn sheep, pigs, chickens, cows, spiders, zombies, skeletons, creepers, Endermen, Slimes (only in certain chunks if not in a **swamp**), **witches**, and Squid.

Also:

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/survival-mode/297051-witch-farm-spawn-rate

> According to the Minecraft Wiki, witches will only spawn at night time in addition to when the witch hut was created. However, witches do despawn when you are out of range so this is likely the problem. Also, if the witch hut is close to another naturally occurring structure such as a jungle temple, there's a chance the witch may have spawned there.

^ this is over a year old.

There are many players who claim that witches spawn during low light levels and despawn when you get far enough away.